# Synchronize PostgreSQL procedure call through REST web service

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, synchronization, jax-rs

I have a `JAX-RS` REST web service that runs on a `JBoss` server and the Java code executes a `PostgreSQL` procedure which runs a query to fetch a value most recently entered in a table, add 1 to it and return the value.

When multiple requests are made to the web service, the query execution is not synchronous and the same value is returned in the `JSON` response.

What is the correct way to synchronize the calls?

Comment: Use select for update

Comment: @zain would this ensure synchronization in all cases?

Comment: It will acquire a write lock for the row, blocking all the other select (...for updates) until the transaction is finished.